# GLUI controls do not appear but they have effect

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, glew, freeglut, glui

I am developing graphic project with OpenGL and using freeglut and glew(v 1.11.0). I want to add sum UI controls with GLUI. I download the source code and build it with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012(I tried GLUI version both 2.35 and 2.36). Add lib file to my project libraries troubleless. So, i can use GLUI in project now.
 But there is a problem about display of controls. I am trying to add my GLUI window as my main Window's subwindow. There is no problem about adding subwindow, reshape or etc. Also, i can add controls to subwindow too. But, when i add them, they don't appear at subwindow. Interestingly, they are actually there. When i click the button place approximately, they have effect that attached callback function to control, it calls that function and makes it job.
Also i tried standalone GLUI window instead of subwindow, but the result is same.
Here is my code:

```
GLUI* glui_subwin = GLUI_Master.create_glui_subwindow(mainWindowID,GLUI_SUBWINDOW_BOTTOM);

GLUI_Button* b_RotateX = glui_subwin->add_button( "Rotate X", 0, (GLUI_CB)CB_rotate);

glui_subwin->add_column(true);

GLUI_Button* b_RotateY = glui_subwin->add_button( "Rotate Y", 1, (GLUI_CB)CB_rotate);
glui_subwin->add_column(true);

GLUI_Button* b_RotateZ = glui_subwin->add_button( "Rotate Z", 2, (GLUI_CB)CB_rotate);
glui_subwin->add_column(true);
...
glui_subwin->set_main_gfx_window(mainWindowID);

GLUI_Master.set_glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
GLUI_Master.set_glutSpecialFunc(NULL);
GLUI_Master.set_glutMouseFunc(mouse);
GLUI_Master.set_glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
GLUI_Master.set_glutIdleFunc(idle);
```

Is there anyone handled this problem or that have any idea what the problem is?
I will be appreciate, if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be, that you created a OpenGL-3 core profile context? GLUI uses functionality deprecated in OpenGL-3 and unless you have a compatibility context it will not work at all. Also remember, that GLUI doesn't know shaders, so if you use shaders, remember to disable them after you're done using them, otherwise GLUI ends up trying to work the fixed function pipeline… fruitlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As u said, it is about deprecated functions. I have used glutInitContextVersion( 3, 2 ); function. It is blocking glui and makes the controls invisible. When i use 3,1 at function, it works properly. But, i have to comment out glutInitContextFlags( GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE ); function call, too.

Comment: @onrrgn: Yes forward compatible implies core profile. Note that "forward compatibility" is something different than "(backward) compatibility profile"; it's in fact the opposite.